# Login into website with two-factor authentication

Tags: html, python-3.x, forms, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Trying to login into lichess.org thru requests library.
lichess has two-factor authentication with input variables as "username", "password", and "token".

Attached below is a screen shot of lichess.org's html layout
[image: lichess.org's login form html layout]

Inspection of form data upon login reveals the "token" variable to be empty.

i still tried to extract the token, just in case, i was missing something.

Below is the code i tried to try to login

> ```
> with requests.Session() as s:
>     #extracting token
>     response = s.get("https://lichess.org/login")
>     ingredientOfSoup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
>     token = ingredientOfSoup.find("input", id= "form3-token").get("value")
>     
>     payload = {
>         "username":username, 
>         "password":password,
>         "token":token
>     }
>     
>     #login request
>     s.post("https://lichess.org/login", data= payload)
>     r = s.get("https://lichess.org/@/Rikkk17/search?perf=2")
>     print(r.status_code)
> ```

Output

> 401

how do i successfully login into lichess.org?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set some default headers, this code works:

```
import requests

payload = {
    'username': 'username',
    'password': 'password',
    'token':'' }

headers = {
    'accept':'*/*',
    'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36',
    }

url = f'https://lichess.org/login'
data = requests.post(url,headers=headers,data=payload)
print(data)
```